# Fixed point iteration converges

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

I found an old problem from notes, which I was not able to solve.
Assume that we have a given (arbitrary) norm $\| \cdot\|$ on $K$ and function $g:K \times K \rightarrow K \times K$ for some compact and convex subset $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, such that
$$
g(x, y) = \pmatrix{g_1(x,y) \\ g_2(x, y)}
$$
where $g_1, g_2$ are Lipschitz in their entries with constants $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma_4 < 1$.
In other words, assume
$$
\| g_1 (x, y) - g_1(x', y') \| \leq \gamma_1 \| x - x'\| + \gamma_2 \| y - y'\| \\
\| g_2 (x, y) - g_2(x', y') \| \leq \gamma_3 \| x - x'\| + \gamma_4 \| y - y'\|
$$
for all $x,y,x', y' \in K$.
Prove that the iterates
$$
(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}) := g(x_{n}, y_{n})
$$
converge to a fixed point of $g$.

It seems that the existence of a fixed point follows from Brouwer's fixed point theorem, but I am stuck with convergence.
I have tried finding an appropriate metric on the space $K\times K$ that makes the function a contraction, i.e, a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \times  \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ that makes
$$
d((x, y), (x', y')) := f(\| x - x'\|, \|y - y'\|)
$$
a complete metric on $K \times K$ and $g$ a contraction, but was not successful so far.
Is the problem possible to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g:[-1,1]^2\to [-1,1]^2$, $g(x,y)=(-(x+y)/2,-(x+y)/2)$. Then
$$
|g_k(x,y)-g_k(x',y')| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-x'| + \frac{1}{2}|y-y'| \quad (k=1,2).
$$
Starting the iteration at $(1,1)$ leads to the sequence
$$
(1,1), ~ (-1,-1), ~ (1,1), ~ (-1,-1) \dots
$$
which is not convergent.

Comment: I suspect one needs a stronger restriction on $\gamma$'s

Comment: It is known that If the spectral radius of the matrix $[\gamma_1,\gamma_2;\gamma_3,\gamma_4]$ is $< 1$ then the sequence of iterates is convergent

Comment: @Gerd Interesting, is there a reference on that? Seems to be a special case of the condition $\gamma_1 + \gamma_2 < 1, \gamma_3 + \gamma_4 < 1$ which would lead to convergence with the $\ell_\infty$ norm

Comment: @ntrstd11 I know this form an old german paper by J. Schröder: Das Iterationsverfahren bei allgemeinerem Abstandsbegriff. Math. Z. 66 (1956), 111-116. I think I have seen it in newer books somewhere but I can't remember.

Comment: @ntrstd11 I just remembered that the the fixed point theorem for matrix contractions is due to Perov. Google search for "fixed point theorem of Perov" leads to several references.